# Requesting Data from API

Tags: api, https, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

[this is the error on serial monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNqb3.png)

I am using ESP8266 NodeMcu and IDE used is Arduino

I don't know what to do, It's been 10 hours now.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

//Provide your own WiFi credentials
const char* ssid = "Kyzer";
const char* password = "@kyzer4$";
//String for storing server response
String response = "";
//JSON document
DynamicJsonDocument doc(2048);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //Initiate WiFi connection
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.print("WiFi connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  //Initiate HTTP client
  HTTPClient http;
  //The API URL
  String request = "https://covid-api.mmediagroup.fr/v1/cases?country=Portugal";
  //Start the request
  http.begin(request);
  //Use HTTP GET request
  http.GET();
  //Response from server
  response = http.getString();
  //Parse JSON, read error if any
  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, response);
  if(error) {
     Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
     Serial.println(error.f_str());
     delay(5000);
     return;
  }
  //Print parsed value on Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("cases: ");
  Serial.println(doc["confirmed"].as<int>());
  Serial.print("recovered: ");
  Serial.println(doc["recovered"].as<int>());
  Serial.print("deaths: ");
  Serial.println(doc["deaths"].as<int>());
  Serial.println("");
  //Close connection  
  http.end();
  //Wait five seconds
  delay(5000);
}
```

Please can someone help me i can't get the data i want and display it on serial monitor, what could be the problem?

Comment: Look through [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/45625/simple-get-request-with-esp8266httpclient) and see if any of them help

Answer (score 2):

The json object that you try to parse has the structure as:

```
  {"All": {
    "confirmed": 378656, 
    "recovered": 304825, 
    "deaths": 6254, 
    "country": "Portugal", 
    "population": 10329506, 
    "sq_km_area": 91982, 
    "life_expectancy": "75.8", 
    "elevation_in_meters": 372, 
    "continent": "Europe", 
    "abbreviation": "PT", 
    "location": "Southern Europe", 
    "iso": 620, 
    "capital_city": "Lisboa", 
    "lat": "39.3999", 
    "long": "-8.2245", 
    "updated": "2020/12/22 23:22:35+00"
    }
  }
```

The elements `confirmed`, `recovered` and `deaths` are all under the `All` element, so you need to get it through assessing the `All` either with `doc["All"]["confirmed"]`, or create a new root json object called `All` so that you can access it with `All["confirmed"]`. See the example:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {

  const char* json = R"({"All": {
    "confirmed": 378656, 
    "recovered": 304825, 
    "deaths": 6254
    }
  }
  )";

  
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(512);
  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, json);
  if(error) {
     Serial.printf("deserializeJson() failed: %s\n", error.c_str());
     delay(5000);
     return;
  }
  //Get confirmed either via doc directly as:
  int confirmed = doc["All"]["confirmed"];
  // Or create a new json object the root object, and access children objects as:
  JsonObject All = doc["All"];
  int recovered = All["recovered"];
  int deaths = All["deaths"];
  Serial.printf("Confirmed: %d, Recovered: %d, Deaths: %d\n",confirmed, recovered, deaths);
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: As the founder of the API, I can confirm that this is indeed the case and the solution :)!